# ¿Existe una regla para el uso de mayúsculas en títulos?

Tags: ortografía, uso-de-mayúsculas

Cuando escribo títulos en español, lo hago normalmente usando las reglas [de Oxford](http://www.ox.ac.uk/public_affairs/services_and_resources/style_guide/capitalisation.html), pero algunas características solo se aplican al inglés. ¿Existe una guía para escribir títulos de artículos, publicaciones, etc. en español?

Comment: Por cierto, te lo he editado pero lo has vuelto a cambiar. No se dice "capitalizar", se dice "escribir con mayúsculas". Capitalizar no tiene la acepción que crees que tiene: http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=capitaliz%E1is

Comment: @MaríaCC en mi país, capitalizar proviene de el uso de la "letra capital". Cuando alguien "capitaliza un titulo" quiere decir, usa *La Mayúscula en la Primera Letra de las Palabras*. Cuando dices "escribir en mayúsculas" se entiende que tu *LO QUIERES ESCRITO TODO EN MAYÚSCULAS*. Es la palabra que utilizamos en Español República Dominicana. En este caso, es el uso de la palabra en una región en particular y esta se entiende.

Comment: Existe solo un español que incluye todas las variantes dialectales, incluida la dominicana. Si la RAE no incluye la acepción en el diccionario es porque obviamente el uso en tu país de este verbo es incorrecto. . De hecho el uso de "letra capital" que tú haces es un anglicismo, una traducción literal de "capital letter", pero está aceptado como correcto debido a su repetido uso. En la lengua española, normalmente una letra capital esa letra del comienzo de los capítulos que es mucho mayor a todas las otras.

Comment: "Capitalizar" se refiere a un asunto de dinero y bancos mercantiles: por ejemplo es común la expresión "comprar una vivienda para capitalizar" en este caso en el futuro cuando se venda el inmueble se obtiene más dinero que el inicialmente se pagó por él.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Según el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas de la Real Academia Española, en su artículo sobre [mayúsculas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp):

> Se escriben con mayúscula la primera palabra del título de cualquier obra de creación (libros, películas, cuadros, esculturas, piezas musicales, programas de radio o televisión, etc.); el resto de las palabras que lo componen, salvo que se trate de nombres propios, deben escribirse con minúscula: *Últimas tardes con Teresa, La vida es sueño, La lección de anatomía, El galo moribundo, Las cuatro estaciones, Las mañanas de la radio, Informe semanal*. En el caso de los títulos abreviados con que se conocen comúnmente determinados textos literarios, el artículo que los acompaña debe escribirse con minúscula: *el Quijote, el Lazarillo, la Celestina*.

Mucho más fácil que en inglés.

Comment: Como lo ice MaríaCC, es idéntico que escribir una oración normal.

Comment: Como lo digo yo no, como lo dice la RAE.

Comment: Como complemento a esta excelente respuesta, la [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/titulos-escritura-correcta/) y otras guías, como la de estilo de la Wikipedia en español, recomiendan extender la regla española a títulos de obras en otras lenguas incrustados en textos en español, aunque es válido respetar la grafía original.