# Is there a word for "capitalization" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

This site has multiple questions about capitalization. I was about to create a tag to group them (like [the English site does](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capitalization), which is the recommended place to check for standard ways of tagging), but I noticed there is no direct word for the concept in Spanish.

We do say ***uso de mayúsculas***, but I cannot find a single word to convey its meaning. I am afraid *capitalización* would be a false friend, since it would kind of mean "to make a place be the capital city of a country/region".

So: is there a word in Spanish for *capitalization*?

Comment: I just found a [related discussion](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5678/existe-una-regla-para-el-uso-de-may%C3%BAsculas-en-t%C3%ADtulos#comment8936_5678) from some time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the word *capitalización* is a false friend in Spanish. It means "the act or process of capitalizing", but *capitalizar* in Spanish means:

> **[capitalizar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7KLccGu)**
>
> 1. tr. Econ. Proveer de capital a una empresa.
> 2. tr. Econ. Convertir algo en capital.
> 3. tr. Econ. Determinar el valor de una inversión en función de las rentas que ha de generar.
> 4. tr. Utilizar en propio beneficio una acción o situación, aunque sean ajenas. *El alcalde capitalizó el triunfo del equipo de fútbol.*

Nothing to do with the use of capital letters, even though in Spanish you can say *[letra capital](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NAwHNtA#7Bhqd21)* for a letter in uppercase. In Spanish we can also say:

> **[letra versal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NAwHNtA#7DFjKYf)**
>
> 1. f. Impr. letra mayúscula.

And thus we have:

> [**letra versalilla**, o **letra versalita**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NAwHNtA#7DM4wdA)
>
> 1. f. Impr. Mayúscula igual en tamaño a la minúscula de la misma clase.

But that is not exactly the same as you refer to. There could be a verb like *versalizar* (which sounds much finer that *mayusculizar*), but there is not. And I cannot find anything else in the DIRAE, so my choices for such a tag would be:

- Uso-de-mayúsculas
- Mayúscula-inicial
- Mayúsculas
- Versales

Comment: So _uso-de-mayúsculas_ or _mayúsculas_ seem to be the best approach. _Versal_ is quite unlikely to come in handy because hardly anybody will think about this word.

Comment: @fedorqui that's why I put it in the last place. :)

Comment: Agreed :) Note by the way that [_versal_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bfJaEpz) has a nice etymology: _De verso1, por emplearse esta clase de letra como inicial de cada uno de ellos, y -al._