# ¿Cómo debo usar las mayúsculas en un título si mi título empieza por un número?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, sintaxis, números, uso-de-mayúsculas

En [¿Existe una regla para el uso de mayúsculas en títulos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5678/5481) vimos que

> Se escriben con mayúscula la primera palabra del título de cualquier obra de creación [...]; el resto de las palabras que lo componen, salvo que se trate de nombres propios, deben escribirse con minúscula

Pero, qué ocurre si mi título empieza por un número, como

"1er Encuentro de Ideas y Propuestas para el Cumplimiento de los Objetivos de Desarrollo Sostenible (ODS) Entre Estudiantes Universitarios y Candidatos de Elección Popular"

Debe ir todo lo demás en minúscula?

Comment: **Nota**: esta es una pregunta que un usuario nuevo publicó como respuesta en el post enlazado. Los moderadores le pedimos que por favor, al ser una pregunta propia y no una respuesta, la publicase como tal. Debido a la falta de seguimiento por parte de este usuario, tuvimos que borrar la pregunta, pero como parecía interesante he decidido rescatarla (y responderla) para el archivo del stack. Sentíos libres de añadir respuestas adicionales.

Answer (score 5):

En [Cifras que inician párrafos](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/cifras-que-inician-parrafos-403/) Fundéu explica que

> en español se recomienda evitar que una oración comience por una cantidad escrita en números, aunque no sea una norma obligatoria. La solución no tiene por qué ser necesariamente escribir la cantidad en letras. Muchas veces basta con cambiar el orden de la frase o redactarla de otra forma
>
> Esto no significa que sea incorrecto comenzar la oración con una cifra. Es una recomendación general que, como otras indicaciones de estilo, depende de diversos factores​. Si alguien opta, por las razones que sea, por cifras, es plenamente legítimo, y podría ser hasta preferible en un contexto dado. **Cuando se opta por [empezar un párrafo con] cifras, la palabra que sigue va en minúscula**.

Sobre [el uso de números](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QHaq7I8KrD6FQAyXTS), la RAE indica ciertas normas. A destacar para este caso

> En la expresión abreviada de los numerales ordinales (→ ordinales), se utilizan cifras seguidas de letras voladas. Como corresponde a las abreviaturas, se escribirá punto entre la cifra y la letra volada

Con respecto a números romanos:

> En la denominación de congresos, campeonatos, certámenes, festivales, etc.: II Congreso Internacional de la Lengua Española, XXIII Feria del Libro de Buenos Aires. Se escriben antepuestos al nombre. Si el número resulta excesivamente complejo, se prefiere, en su lugar, el uso de las abreviaturas de los numerales correspondientes: **78.o Campeonato Mundial de Ajedrez**.

Y lo cierto es que "primer", pues no es complejo (lo que no justificaría usar "1er" o "1.<sup>er</sup>") y es un número que puede expresarse en una sola palabra.

Viendo lo indicado por la RAE, sí se usarían mayúsculas en el título (recordemos que la recomendación de Fundéu es para un **párrafo** y no un título), por lo que diríamos

> 1.<sup>er</sup> Encuentro de Ideas y Propuestas para el Cumplimiento de los Objetivos de Desarrollo Sostenible (ODS) Entre Estudiantes Universitarios y Candidatos de Elección Popular"

Nunca

> 1.<sup>er</sup> encuentro de ideas y propuestas

Aunque sería mucho mejor

> Primer Encuentro de Ideas y Propuestas

(hasta que ese ordinal sea un número que resulta excesivamente complejo).

Por cierto, el post enlazado en la pregunta, hace referencia a un título **de obra de creación**. Este es el título de un certamen. Son dos cosas diferentes y por tanto en este caso se hace un uso de las mayúsculas distinto al descrito en la respuesta del post enlazado.

Por el contrario si lo que empezamos es un párrafo, la palabra después del número va en minúscula.

> Me he gastado 1000 euros *entre pitos y flautas*. **500 euros** en pitos y otros 500 en flautas.

(esta última es un mal ejemplo, pues otra recomendación es "No es recomendable mezclar en un mismo enunciado números escritos con cifras y números escritos con letra")