# Capitalization in a heading in Spanish

Tags: uso-de-mayúsculas

Is it correct to only capitalize the letter of the first word in the heading of a presentation?

Comment: Yes as answered before (in spanish) here https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/5680/11102

Comment: Yes. The rules are the same as those for a normal sentence.