# What are the rules of title case in Spanish?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-mayúsculas

The rules of title case in English vary from publication to publication, but they are mostly standardized.

Generally, you capitalize the first letter of every except for Articles (a, an, the), Coordinating Conjunctions (and, but, for), Short (fewer than 4 letters) and Prepositions (at, by, to, etc.).

How do the rules function in Spanish? Are the rules any stricter in Spanish than English?

For example, in English, if you put "Alexander And The Terrible", although it wouldn't be common in many style guides to capitalize "And" and "The", it wouldn't be wrong to do either (so long as you were consistent like that with all titles).  Does this flexibility exist in Spanish?

For example, would "¡Perfectos Para Practicar Tus Habilidades En Inglés!" be acceptable even though it capitalizes prepositions.

I feel that some people may regard this to be a bad subjective question, as the title case varies from style guide to style guide in English. However, the purpose of this question is to establish if such variation exists in Spanish, and also to establish which are the most likely rules in Spanish (similar to how English has common rules even though there is variation between publications). As these are both answerable questions, I think this question meets the requirements of Stack Exchange.

Comment: So just to summarise: Only the first letter of the first word is capitals unless it is a proper name (such as Mary, Inglés [as in the language], or a town name). Is that correct? I am only a beginner at Spanish, which is why I am double-checking, just in case I misunderstood the link you gave (which is only in Spanish).

Comment: @big_smile correct, except that names of languages (and of days and months) are written with small letters too (*español, inglés, lunes, febrero*). Names of places or people are written with capital letters.

Comment: @wimi What about book titles: Is the first letter of each word in the title capitalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spanish is strict as to the rule of capitalizing only the first letter in a title or in a headline.

This question has already been addressed [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5678/existe-una-regla-para-el-uso-de-may%C3%BAsculas-en-t%C3%ADtulos).

Further reference can be found [here](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/titulos-escritura-correcta/#:%7E:text=Los%20t%C3%ADtulos%20de%20las%20obras,el%20t%C3%ADtulo%20incluye%20alguno%3A%20Cien).

Comment: So just to summarise: Only the first letter of the first word is capitals unless it is a proper name (such as Mary, Inglés [as in the language], or a town name). Is that correct? I am only a beginner at Spanish, which is why I am double-checking, just in case I misunderstood the link you gave (which is only in Spanish).