# Mayúsculas en la segunda palabra

Tags: gramática, uso-de-mayúsculas

Estaba redactando un formulario; cuando pasó revisión, me corrigieron la mayúsculas en las siguientes palabras:

Antes de la edición:

- Apellido paterno
- Primer nombre

Después de la edición:

- Apellido Paterno
- Primer Nombre

Nótese que la mayúscula corregida es en la palabras **paterno** y **nombre**. Quisiera saber bajo qué regla gramatical se plantea esa corrección o si es una convención entre los escribanos.

Comment: ¿Quién hizo esa revisión?

Comment: Estoy casi seguro de que la forma correcta es con minúsculas. Por ejemplo, el [formulario de contacto de la RAE](https://www.rae.es/contacto-rae) utiliza minúsculas en las segundas palabras de los títulos de los campos.

Comment: La revisión lo realizó mi empleador.

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5678/existe-una-regla-para-el-uso-de-may%c3%basculas-en-t%c3%adtulos?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Revisé el [Diccionarion panamericano de dudas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/may%C3%BAsculas) sobre el uso de mayúsculas, pero no encontré algo que indicara que debían ser mayúsculas iniciales al principio de cada frase que nos enseñas. Lo que yo diría es que puede ser estilo personalizado o siguiendo pautas de un estilo de formato establecido por alguna organización, por ejemplo el [APA](http://normas-apa.com/titulos-subtitulo-normas-apa/#:%7E:text=Los%20t%C3%ADtulos%20y%20subt%C3%ADtulos%20en%20APA%20le%20ayudan,misma%20fuente%20que%20se%20usa%20en%20el%20documento.).

*Lo siguiente es info añadida contestando al primer comentario de Monkey D. Erick:*

De acuerdo a las [normas APA](https://normas-apa.org/formato/titulos-y-subtitulos/), en los títulos y subtítulos cada palabra inicia con mayúscula (excepto palabras menores que no sean inicio de oración o similar, ej., en, o, y).

Comment: Dudo que el formato APA tengo ese tipo de corrección, aunque no he leído todas su reglas; lo utilizo seguido y nunca me encontré con algo parecido.